# How to find text box content and replace it using docx4j with java?

Tags: java, docx4j

I am using docx4j open source for manipulating the word file, I am using the Xml file for searching the content by Xpath.

In the word document there is a heading if I click on it it is showing "Tool Box Tool Format" In this text box first line is subject and second is Title.

```
ex:-       Doc_name<>
           Doc_Info
```

where Doc_name is subject.

I am able to find this object via x-path as follow.

```
Stringxpath="//w:p[w:sdt[w:sdtContent[w:r[w:t[contains(text(),'"+SectionName+"')]]]]]";
```

In `SectionName` variable I am passing the `Doc_Name`.
But using this X-path I am getting both subject and Title.
But I am not able to change the subject, I need change only subject.

Comment: Your question is not that clear.  Please add the XML for the text box.